# How to set ticklabels in bold on x-axis when using usetex=True

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I have the following small program in which I use `rc("text", usetex = True)` in order to allow some formatting.

I thought that the line `ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), weight='bold')` would show in **bold** the numbers showed on the `x-axis`.

But there's something I clearly didn't understand in all the instructions I read here and there, especially on some `SO` posts. So now I don't know how to get out of it...

What would be the simplest change in this program to plot these numbers in bold?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc("text", usetex = True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6, 3), tight_layout = True)

ax.set_yticks([i for i in range(0, 10+1, 1)])
ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(0, 100+1, 10)])
ax.tick_params(axis = "both", labelsize = 15)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), weight='bold')
ax.set_title(r"$\underline{\textbf{Proper}}$")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.set_xticklabels([fr'\textbf{{{v}}}' for v in ax.get_xticks()])` [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIHlI.png)

Comment: Many thanks to `Trenton McKinney` for his simple line of code! The `{{{v}}}`looks a bit strange to me, but it works...

Comment: The normal implementation with a `string` is `r'\textbf{my text}'`, however, we're using an `f-string` to access the variable `v` and you can't do `{{v}}`, you must do `{{{v}}}`. If you only do `ax.set_xticklabels([fr'\textbf{v}' for v in ax.get_xticks()])` only the first character of the number is bold.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the fact. Nevertheless I still don't understand the logic of the number of brackets needed. But don't worry, this is outside my question...